# $0$-th cohomology of derived tensor product.

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, derived-functors, derived-categories

I want to show the following lemma:

> [Lemma 4.8.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.1035.pdf) Let $M$ and $N$ be two complexes of $A$-module whose homology is concentrated in negative degrees. Then there is an isomorphism
> $$
> H^0(M \otimes^{\mathbb{L}}_A N) \simeq H^0(M) \otimes_A H^0(N)
> $$

Since $H^0(M)\simeq \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}(A)} (A,M)$, we only need to show
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}(A)} (A,M\otimes^{\mathbb{L}}_A N) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}(A)} (A,M) \otimes_A \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}(A)} (A,N)
$$
Is this isomorphism true?

This may seem trivial to you, but the relationship between derived Hom functors and derived tensor product functors does confuse me. Thank you.

Comment: You should not use the derived hom here, it only makes things harder. Just take two complexes $M,N$ in negative degree, $P,Q$ two projectives resolutions (also in negative degrees), then $M\otimes_A^{\mathbb{L}} N=P\otimes_A Q$. Compute $H^0(P\otimes_A Q)$ and see that this is the same as $H^0(M)\otimes_A H^0(N)$.